# How to Change Multiple Format Parameters of a Cell Based on Its Value?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a code that changes the style properties of a range of selected cells based on the cell value.

It worked when I only changed the text-color or font but since I added multiple arguments to each if the code does nothing. I also don't get an error.

```
Dim userRange As Range

Set userRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range", Type:=8)

For Each cell In Selection

        If cell.Value < 0 Then cell.Font.FontStyle = "Comic Sans MS" & cell.Font.Size = 18 & cell.Font.Color = vbRed

        If cell.Value >= 0 And cell.Value <= 500 Then cell.Font.Bold = True & cell.Font.Italic = True & cell.Font.Underline = True

        If cell.Value > 500 And cell.Value <= 1000 Then cell.Font.FontStyle = "Monotype Corsiva" & cell.Font.Color = vbBlue & cell.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleDouble

        If cell.Value > 1000 Then cell.Font.FontStyle = "Arial" & cell.Font.Bold = True & cell.Font.Italic = True & cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen & cell.Font.Color = vbWhite

Next cell
```

I think I'm really close but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong! I hope my explanation is clear since I'm not really used to programming/scripting.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you actually want to add consecutive assignments in one code line you'll have to use the `:` character as line separator (this is no *logical* AND replacement, however) instead of the ampersand `&`. Otherwise it's more readable to use separate code lines within the `If` condition.

Comment: Ok, I think I need to study a little more before I write code like this! Thanks for the tip! I was already thinking my code looked a little messy!

Comment: Note if you need to run this more than once and values can change between runs, you need to clear/reset *all* style properties first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should fix it. Your old code wasn't executing each line. You have to insert a space of a `:` instead of an `&`. Also, it saves some typing if you use the `With` feature to save some typing. Also take note that you are using `ActiveCell`, make sure that's intentional.

```
Dim userRange As Range, d As Double, cell As Range 'added more variables

Set userRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range", Type:=8)

For Each cell In userRange.Cells
    d = cell.Value

    With cell.Font

        If d < 0 Then
            .FontStyle = "Comic Sans MS"
            .Size = 18
            .Color = vbRed
        End If


        If d >= 0 And d <= 500 Then
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = True
            .Underline = True

        End If


        If d > 500 And d <= 1000 Then
            .FontStyle = "Monotype Corsiva"
            .Color = vbBlue
            ActiveCell.Underline = xlDouble ' is this right?
        End If


        If d > 1000 Then
            .FontStyle = "Arial"
            .Bold = True
            .Italic = True
            .Color = vbGreen 'this is being undone in the next line of code.
            .Color = vbWhite 
        End If

    End With

Next cell
```

Comment: I used this code thanks! It's way cleaner and works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You defined userRange but later on you are looping over cells in selection. Also you are using & incorrectly. You can try this:

```
Dim userRange As Range

Set userRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range", Type:=8)

For Each cell In userRange

        If cell.Value < 0 Then
            cell.Font.FontStyle = "Comic Sans MS"
            cell.Font.Size = 18 & cell.Font.Color = vbRed
        End If

        If cell.Value >= 0 And cell.Value <= 500 Then
            cell.Font.Bold = True & cell.Font.Italic = True
            cell.Font.Underline = True
        End If

        If cell.Value > 500 And cell.Value <= 1000 Then
            cell.Font.FontStyle = "Monotype Corsiva"
            cell.Font.Color = vbBlue
            cell.Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleDouble
        End If

        If cell.Value > 1000 Then
            cell.Font.FontStyle = "Arial"
            cell.Font.Bold = True
            cell.Font.Italic = True
            cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            cell.Font.Color = vbWhite
        End If
Next cell
```

Comment: That looks pretty similar to my answer but I'll give you a tick because I'm going for the "I'm a good darn citizen" badge!"

Comment: I started working on this in excel module but before I had a chance to paste my answer you was already here. Anyway thanks and grab a one too.

Comment: Thanks that works! I think I'll read some more about how to use the & function then. I also edited the double .Font.Color which was supposed to be .Interior.Color